# how to make transparent png ImageView in android studio

Tags: android, imageview, transparent

I want to make myimage appears transparent so i decided to make the "broken" image into png. Then I tried it. but it failed.

instead of this
broken png xml

[image]

it appears look like this
broken png black

[image]

and here is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/broken"
         android:alpha=".75">
```

Comment: Can you post the png as file?

Comment: Is your theme using a black background?

Comment: Most probably due to you are using a dark theme.

Answer (score 0):

Add parent with white background

e.g.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/broken"
    android:alpha=".75">


<YOUR CODE>


</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this not sure this is what you want

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/broken"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please let me know if it doesn't meet your needs

Comment: thank you for the answer but it doesn't work. It appears all black now. I think it is because of my Dark theme.